# Accessing instance variable inside of a callback function

Tags: javascript, node.js

What I'm trying to do is pretty trivial: I am creating an object, or better I'm defining a function that is instantiating the object, and then I have another function that reads from a file and gets a callback when the reading is finished. The function is assigned to the prototype of the object, so that it's created only once and not every time I'm creating a new instance of it.

```
var fs = require('fs');

var CrazyObject = function () {
    this.craziness = 'this is sooo crazy';
};

CrazyObject.prototype.crazyFunction = function (file) {
    fs.readFile(file, function (err, result) {
        // here i can't access the craziness!
    });

    // but here i can
};

exports.CrazyObject = CrazyObject;
```

As the example shows, the problem is that inside the callback I can't access the variable assigned when the object is created.

Comment: That's a *property*, not a variable.

Comment: Well since the value can change it's still a variable :) semantically speaking of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) your callback function to the correct context:

```
fs.readFile(file, (function (err, result) {
    console.log(this.craziness);
}).bind(this));
```

Comment: It was trivial indeed. Thanks!